# Terraform how to to get access to outputs inside terraform if using an S3 backend for the tfstate file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to access the value of a terraform output that I generate using the locals.tf when running terraform apply.  My understanding is if I  am using S3 backend for my state file, I can not access my outputs just by doing a terraform output. So how can I access the outputs in this case?

My locals.tf is as follows:

```
locals {
  groups = {
    mettle0 = {
      description = "mettle description 0"
      rules = [{
        description = "rule description 0",
      },{
        description = "rule description 1",
      }]
    },
    mettle1 = {
      description = "mettle description 1"
      rules = [{
        description = "rule description 0",
      },{
        description = "rule description 1",
      }]
    }
  }
  rules = { for k,v in local.groups : k => v.rules }
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
output "mettlerules" {
  value = yamlencode("${local.rules}")
}
```

If I don't declare an S3 backend, running terraform apply creates my output as expected. And I can recall this by doing a terraform output too:

```
Outputs:

mettlerules = <<EOT
"mettle0":
- "description": "rule description 0"
- "description": "rule description 1"
"mettle1":
- "description": "rule description 0"
- "description": "rule description 1"

EOT
```

But if I apply S3 backend and then run the terraform apply, I see the outputs printed to screen.  But when I run terraform output I get:

```
│ Warning: No outputs found
│ 
│ The state file either has no outputs defined, or all the defined outputs are empty. Please define an
│ output in your configuration with the `output` keyword and run `terraform refresh` for it to become
│ available. If you are using interpolation, please verify the interpolated value is not empty. You can
│ use the `terraform console` command to assist.
```

So how can I retrieve my output after running terraform apply with an S3 backend, any ideas?

Comment: There should be no difference in how output works. You must be doing something incorrectly. Maybe running wrong version of your tf code?

Comment: @Marcin I have since found the way to obtain the results of the output. It involves using a  data resource to obtain the results of the output from the state file on S3 and then using that in a local_file resource to save it to a local file: ```resource "local_file" "mettle_yaml_file" {
    content  = yamlencode("${data.terraform_remote_state.network.mettlerules}")
    filename = "mettlerules.yml"
}
``` however it doesn't write the above outputs to the local file but instead just an empty ```{}```. Any ideas on how to get the outputs into the local file?